# Eclipse: how to open header file from #include line

Tags: eclipse

In Visual Studio one can right click on the #include line and open the header file. Is this possible in Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, just put your cursor on the included file, right click and select `Open Declaration`:

[image]